# Can rPi control a computer and provide backup?

Tags: pi-2, backup, computer-vision

Im just wondering, is rPi is able control a computer (on/off), check if the computer is working (using ping test). If the computer is not able to use, the rPi will automatically switch on another computer (backup computer). Will it be possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, the Pi can switch relays on and off and ping.

Answer (score 1):

> Im just wondering, is rPi is able control a computer (on/off)

This is more a question about *how* the other computer can be turned on and off.  If you can log in remotely and shut it down, obviously it is easy enough.

> check if the computer is working (using ping test)

Yes.

> automatically switch on another computer

Again, this depends on how the other computer can be turned on and off.  Many of them will respond to [wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN), in which case the answer is yes.  If not, and simply turning power on is sufficient, then as joan points out, the pi can be used to control a [relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay).

Answer (score 0):

As for doing this the information in this [link](http://www.mupuf.org/blog/2013/05/11/wtrpm-a-web-based-wt-suite-to-power-up-slash-down-your-computers/) would be very helpful if you wanted to create something to boot up your computer or backup. Very nice article to really help out.